# Timezone is not changing after updating php.ini

Tags: php, hosting, godaddy-api

I have **hosted my PHP website on godaddy**, it is working fine. But the problem is it is showing **timezone** to American/Phoneix which i want to change in Asia/Karachi.

So i found that i have to put this (**date.timezone = "Asia/Karachi"**) line in PHP.ini file. So i have paste it into php.ini which is located at root of my site. but still  timezone to American/Phoneix. What i am doing wrong?

I have also tried to write this (**date.timezone = "Asia/Karachi"**) line in htaccess file but it also didn't work.

*Remember i am unable to reload my server at godaddy.*

Comment: how to change ini file in godaddy:
https://uk.godaddy.com/help/change-php-settings-26379
and make it take effect: 
https://uk.godaddy.com/help/phpiniuserini-changes-not-taking-effect-5647

Comment: Thanks i am checking it

Comment: goddady is a shirt host, move

Comment: @rtfm it seems that you are right, how you experience it?

Comment: @Tamar it didn't work. can you help

Comment: change the timezone within the php code:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: @Tamar so i have to add this everywhere, where i am using time? can't i do this within php.ini i tried this at local php.ini it worked pefectly but it is not working on server.

Comment: usually php.ini does it, but you told us it doesn't work for you

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the time zone in your `.htaccess`:

```
php_value date.timezone Asia/Karachi
```

If this doesn't work try to use `ini_set`:

```
<?php
ini_set('date.timezone', 'Asia/Karachi');
// or
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Karachi');
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using php 5.6. In php.ini should you try remove "" likes that:

> date.timezone = Asia/Karachi

or config in your php file :

> date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Karachi");